# Компилятор выдаёт много ошибок, не одна перегруженная функция не может преобразовать все типы аргументов, отсутсвуют экземпляры конструктора

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Area
{
public:
    string name;
    string mo;
    string ko;
    Area(string a)
    {
        name = a;
    }
    virtual char* getname()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual  char* getplace()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
class Savannah:public Area
{
public:
    Savannah(string a, string m, string k) :Area(a)
    {
        name = a;
        mo = m;
        ko = k;
    }
};
class Jungle :public Area
{
public:
    Jungle (string a, string m, string k) :Area(a)
    {
        name = a;
        mo = m;
        ko = k;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Savannah sav1("Лев");
    Savannah sav2("Лев");
    Savannah sav3("Лев");
    Jungle jung1("a");
    Jungle jung2("a");
    Jungle jung3("a");
    Area* places[] = {&sav1,&sav2,&sav3, &jung1, &jung2, &jung3 };
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лог сборки следует приводить в виде текста.

Answer (score 2):

Для `Savannah` у вас единственный конструктор со сколькими строками?

```
Savannah(string a, string m, string k)
```

Считаем - a - один, m - два, k - три...

А сколько вы передаете?

```
Savannah sav1("Лев");
Savannah sav2("Лев");
Savannah sav3("Лев");
```

Для `Jungle` посчитайте сами...